# Say I have a file's path, how do I reference that file's directory from the command line?

Tags: bash, directory

I can type:

```
dirname ~/home/blah/file.zip
```

for instance, and this works fine alone, but when I use this syntax as the parameter for some command it always reads 'dirname' as the desired directory. i.e.:

```
cd dirname ~/home/blah/file.zip
bash: cd: dirname: No such file or directory
```

Basically, how do I get 'dirname *file*' to be read as one entity?

Comment: Command substitution strips trailing newlines, which is a problem that quoting alone cannot solve.  No sensible user or developer would put a newline at the end of any file name, but a malicious or clueless one might since Unix filesystems allow it.  Parameter substitution is not vulnerable to this issue, and there are other reasons to prefer it to command substitution.  The [currently accepted answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39545/9537) uses command substitution, while [@Gilles' answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39560/9537) which uses parameter expansion is the correct one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cd "$(dirname ~/home/blah/file.zip)"
```

`$(` is a form of command substitution. The [BashGuide Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) has some good information about this process.

Comment: See my comment on the question for why parameter substitution (e.g. [@Gilles' answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39560/9537)) is better approach.  It also uses one less external process.

Comment: @jw013, is your answer posix compliant? I can't remember any unix without the `dirname` command and if it isn't on the performance critical path, then `dirname` is easier to understand. I'm upvoting you though because I like pure shell solutions.

Answer (score 3):

(I won't repeat the command substitution feature already shown in other answers.)

If this comes up often, you can define a function. For example, put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
d () {
  if ! [ -d "$1/." ]; then
    set -- "${1%/*}"
  fi
  cd -- "$1"
}
```

With this definition, you can run `d /path/to/directory` to change to the specified directory, or `d /path/to/file` to change to the directory containing the specified file (i.e. `/path/to`).

For this particular command, you can remove the last word by editing the command: with default key bindings, from the end of the line, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to move back to the previous word and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to erase the word on the right. On most terminals, from the end of the line, you can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to directly erase the word on the left.

If the path is a directory, `~/home/blah/subdir/..` designates the same directory as `~/home/blah`.

In zsh, you can tack `(:h)` at the end of a path to strip off the file name and keep only the directory part. (It's `h` for “head”; `t` for “tail” retains only the file part.) You can use other [history modifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) within `(:…)` after a path or glob.

```
cd ~/home/blah/file.zip(:h)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `"$(cmd)"` form recommended by Chris is safest, but this is easier to type and will usually work just as well:

```
$ cd `dirname ~/home/blah/file.zip`
```

The difference is that the backticks form [can be confused](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04) by certain characters in the command it's expanding. For a simple command like the one you show, you can immediately tell that it's not going to be a problem. For a shell script that needs to accept arbitrary arguments, it's safer to use the double-quoted `$()` form.

Comment: There are two differences here: the presence of double quotes, and the backticks vs `$(…)`. The double quotes protect special characters in the output of the command; it's often safe to leave them off on the command line (if you know you don't have any troublesome file names), but not in a script. The backticks have weird rules for quoting the command itself, but they're ok to use for a simple command with no tested `\` or backtick; in scripts, you might as well forget they exist and stick to `$(…)`.

Answer (score 1):

(This is just a reply to @gilles answer as it is too big for a comment)

As Gilles already pointed out you can create a function which automatically perform the required function. But instead of using some random name you could also just redefine `cd`:

For zsh:

```
cd() {
    if (( ${#argv} == 1 )) && [[ -f ${1} ]]; then
        builtin cd ${1:h}
    else
        builtin cd "$@"
    fi
}
```

For bash:

```
cd() {
    if [ $# == 1 ] && [[ -f ${1} ]]; then
        builtin cd "$(dirname ${1})"
    else
        builtin cd "$@"
    fi
}
```

This will allow you to do something like `cd /path/to/file` and it will automatically change into the directory of the specific file. Of course you can use the bash version also with zsh.